# Sagemaker Studio Pipeline Execution Step Graphs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker-studio

In the right sidebar of the Sagemaker Studio Pipeline Executions page, when you select a step (of a running/complete execution) it has 4 sections - `Status`, `Metrics`, `Files` and `Charts`.

What are `Charts`? I cannot find any documentation on how to produce a chart in a pipeline step and have it display here. My guess is you could create a learning curve or confusion matrix (or I guess whatever you want) and save it to some output channel but what are the requirements/constraints for this to work?

In the right sidebar of the Sagemaker Studio Pipeline Executions page, when you select a step it has 4 sections - `Status`, `Metrics`, `Files` and `Charts`.

What are `Charts`? I cannot find any documentation on how to produce a chart in a pipeline step and have it display here. My guess is you could create a learning curve or confusion matrix (or I guess whatever you want) and save it to some output channel but what are the requirements/constraints for this to work?